# Deep Reinforcement Learning Hands on, chapter 7. Can't get tensorflow to work

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorboard, reinforcement-learning

Doing a course in Machine Learning and can't get Tensorboard to work. I have saved runs from running a DQN and I write:

`tensorboard -logdir runs`

With the folliwng result:

> 2019-12-28 18:32:04.265065: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
>   TensorBoard 1.7.0 at http://david-linux:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)

So I click the link and get: 
No dashboards are active for the current data set.

> Probable causes:
>   You haven’t written any data to your event files
>   TensorBoard can’t find your event files.

I also get this result after having the code running for a while:

> "W1228 18:34:34.186506 Thread-2 application.py:272] path /[[_dataImageSrc]] not found, sending 404
>   W1228 18:34:34.205581 Thread-2 application.py:272] path /[[_imageURL]] not found, sending 404"

Running this on **Linux** using ***Anaconda Python version 3.6*** because that is what the course book uses. Have no idea what the above errors means, quite new to coding in general and reinforment learning in particular.

Answer (score 1):

It could be caused if the browser isn't updated.  You could also try installing the latest version of Tensorboard:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow-tensorboard 
pip install tensorboard
```

Also try using different browsers.

Comment: Well done sir! The book I am following recommended getting 1.7.0 for tensorboard since that is what it uses, but considering tensorboard is only a reporting tool in this instance it seems to have worked fine with a much more recent version. Perhaps the old version is incompatible with the current website? In any case, after uninstalling both tensorboard and tensorflow multiple times I was able to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try going to http://localhost:6006 instead? It looks like your hostname is not one that actually resolves in DNS.

Comment: This game me the exact same error. Reinstalling tensorboard multiple times seems to have finally made it work.